# How to set client specific timezone and date

Tags: date, grails

pardon me if it seems to be a duplicate question. 
I have seen many posts already on this topic. However after trying many examples could not find the solution to my problem.

I tried this code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH )
Date newDate = sdf.parse(sdf.format( new Date( dateTimeString ) ) )
```

However the second line of code always converts the date to the server specific date and timezone which i don't want. I also tried the following

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH )


    log.info "+++++++++++++++++hidden date ++++++++ " + params.hiddenGameDateTime.substring(35, 38)
    log.info "x = " + sdf.format( new Date ( params.hiddenGameDateTime ))
    String tzone = params.hiddenGameDateTime.substring(35, 38)
    sdf.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( tzone ) )
    log.info "Timezone = " + sdf.getTimeZone().getDisplayName()
```

Please note that

```
sdf.format( new Date( dateTimeString ) )
```

gives me the desired result, however it gives me the string value of the date and the actual value to be stored in database is of the Data type date which can't hold the string value. 
the value for date and time in my case gets converted to PST date and time. how can i avoid this. The user input date with timezone should be stored in the database as it is with no change in date and timezone.

Answer (score 1):

An observation: The constructor `new Date( dateTimeString )` is deprecated. A better replacement would be something like that:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfOriginal = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date d = sdfOriginal.parse(dateTimeString);
```

Furthermore: An expression like `sdf.parse(sdf.format(...))` using the same format object does not make much sense.

But most important, your statement "the second line of code always converts the date to the server specific date and timezone" seems to be based on test output like:

```
System.out.println(newDate);
```

This implicitly uses toString() which is based on jvm default time zone, in your case the server time zone. But keep in mind, the internal state of j.u.Date does not reference any time zone. A Date is just a container for a long, namely the seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z in UTC time zone, that is a global time.

Additional remark:

If you need the client time zone (in a scenario with multiple users in different time zones) to create user-specific formatted date strings, then you indeed need to store the time zone preference of every user in the database, so you can use this information for output in an expression like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("{pattern}";
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("{user-preference-time-zone}");
String userOutput = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: he need date in user specific time zone not DateString

Comment: @SureshkumarPanneerselvan See my additional remark for user specific time zone.

Comment: i calculated timezoneoffset using javasacript and passed it as a json to the java function to set the timezone the following way    clientTimeZoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
 clientTimeZoneOffset = ((clientTimeZoneOffset<0? '+':'-')+ // Note the reversed sign!
           pad(parseInt(Math.abs(clientTimeZoneOffset/60)), 2)+
           pad(Math.abs(clientTimeZoneOffset%60), 2));

Comment: I get the timezone offset from javascript. I did something like this        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT".concat(offset))) .. this also is not working'

Answer (score 0):

Date is always jvm timezone specific. You need to normalize it to standard time and store it in DB to cater with different timezone servers.

Comment: Means the default value is server locale. If the server is in India it was UTC+5.30. So you need to normalize it to UTC and viceversa.

Comment: I disagree. First a Locale is not the same as a time zone. Second j.u.Date is only a global time and does not hold any locale or time zone. It is only its toString()-method which uses default time zone information for output.